# Внезапные знаки за реферальные ссылки

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Сегодня утром внезапно обнаружил вот такую кипу уведомлений. Что произошло? Был какой-то пересчёт или это какая-то накрутка? Особенно смущает полный комплект знаков (за 25, 300 и 1000 уникальных ip) на одном [сообщении](//stackoverflow.com/a/6348239/4928642).

[image: скриншот 1]

[image: скриншот 2]

Comment: ну так радоваться надо)

Comment: Хм. Ну вот 19 часов назад как-то много публицистов прибавилось: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist было 4 за всё время существования сайта, а теперь 16

Comment: Да, похоже это ошибка. Мне тоже прилетел "Диктор" за ссылку на ответ, которую я нигде и никогда не публиковал, после того как я дал ссылку на тему о литературе по С++ в чате C/C++ в ответ на сообщение `@Stranger in the Q`

Comment: А вот он дважды засвечен в той [теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1000153/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-0-1-2-3-4-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-2-3-4/1000165#1000165), на которую я якобы ссылался, за что и получил "Диктора"

Comment: Такие у меня исходные данные для отладки (расследования инцидента)

Comment: @AK, а мне публициста только на английском дали. А местного мне яндекс подарил)))

Comment: @avp, а на enSO золотых публицистов 21 час назад было выдано около 5000 (примерно 80 страниц).

Comment: @Qwertiy, не знаю что именно происходит, но явно не все ладно в Датском королевстве...

Comment: Надо бы, наверное, целостность базы данных проверить

Comment: @avp, так у ruSO и enSO разные базы.

Comment: Мне тоже две таких ачивки прилетело. Причём, кажется, за одно и то же

Comment: Может пофиксили баг, из-за которого они раньше не выдавались?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко, то [пофиксили баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340289/260198).

После чего сделали перерасчёт знаков "Диктор", "Усилитель", "Публицист".