# Проблемы с метой на мобильном приложении

Tags: дефект, мобильное-приложение

С сегодняшнего утра (13.12) в мобильном приложении наблюдаются сбои в работе с метой - при попытке поставить плюс/минус или что-то написать выскакивает форма, что не "зарегистрирован на мете, присоединиться"? После "присоединения" некоторое время все в порядке, потом опять то же самое.

Приложение не обновлялось, на основном сайте такого нет.

Comment: Разные проявления [одной и той же проблемы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9866/%d0%92%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8)?

Comment: @avp, ну у меня всё работает, я не в приложении и мне даже шапки дали за знаки.